# UIbutton in UItableview with different actions for each button in each cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton

In my `UITableView` I'm attempting to have a button that will have a different action for each cell i.e. links to different `viewController`, for each button but i've only managed to achieve it with one.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return courseTitle.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.image_view.image = courseImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = courseTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.tableButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tableButton.addTarget(self, action: "Test", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

     return cell
}

@IBAction func Test(sender: AnyObject){

    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SuccessfulLogin", sender: nil)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that tag value for that and change your `selector` syntax also

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.image_view.image = courseImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = courseTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.tableButton.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.tableButton.addTarget(self, action: "test:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

@IBAction func test(sender: UIButton){

    let row = sender.tag
    switch(row) {
        case 0:
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue1", sender: nil)
        case 1:
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue2", sender: nil)
        case 2:
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("Segue3", sender: nil)
        default:
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome mate, Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have just few cells you can do it like so:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

    cell.image_view.image = courseImages[indexPath.row]
    cell.title.text = courseTitle[indexPath.row]
    cell.tableButton.tag = indexPath.row

    switch indexPath.row {

    case 0:
        cell.tableButton.addTarget(self, action: "TestA", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    case 1:
        cell.tableButton.addTarget(self, action: "TestB", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    case 2:
        cell.tableButton.addTarget(self, action: "TestC", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    default:
        cell.tableButton.addTarget(self, action: "TestD", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    }

    return cell
}

func TestA(sender: AnyObject){   // no need for @IBAction as you set the target action while setting the cell
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("SuccessfulLogin", sender: nil)
}

func TestB(sender: AnyObject){
    print("Second button action")
}

func TestC(sender: AnyObject){
    print("Third button action")
}

func TestD(sender: AnyObject){
    print("All other buttons action")
}
```

Comment: I've typed the above code from head so it might include some typing errors. If that's the case let me know so I'll fix that.